# Exponential Big-O Equivalency

Tags: big-o, computer-science

I've been trying to solve a question for a few days now. I've looked around the web for help and the only answer I found is the opposite of my conclusion.

Here's the question:

```
   **3^n = 2^(O(n))   True or False?**
```

The conclusion is "TRUE" and the correct answer is:

```
3^n = 2^(O(n)) since 3^n = 2^(n*log_2(3)) = 2^(O(n))
```

The problem is that I have no idea how the answer was determined. A step by step process would be the best explanation for me. In other words, how was 3^n = 2^n converted into a log, how did we determine both the constant and a starting point where n >= k?

EDIT: 
Maybe it would be easier to explain where the 2's, and 3's are coming from in this educated guess.The solution has ONE 3, and TWO 2's.

```
If f(n) = 3^n and g(n) = 2^n 

The 3 in 2^(n*log_2(3)) must be coming from f(n)?
The 2 in 2^(n*log_2(3)) must be coming from g(n)'s base?
----> Is the log_2 a constant??
```

In other words, if the question was

```
7^n  = 4^(O(n)) ?
```

Would the correct answer be

```
4^(n*log_2(7))

How is k determined, where all n >= k?
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: your professor is correct (somewhat unsurprisingly!). what don't you understand about his reasoning?

Comment: It's not my professor xD. My professor hasn't talked about this at all. I guess i don't understand their answer at all, or why mine is wrong. According to the book, my answer should be correct right? What am I missing?

Comment: your reasoning is wrong because you are picking the 'c' constant the 'wrong way around'. you find the 'c' for which when n > N the expression holds true

Comment: Are you sure? Because, if that's the case, then why would the question ask "true or false?"  if you can only get a true answer?

Otherwise, can you explain their answer? I have no idea how they came to that answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Exponential_time may be useful as another reference here.

Comment: That link only stated the form that I used, and does not explain how to get the answer at all. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The professor is correct. Their logic is as follows:
`3^n = (2^log_2(3))^n = 2^(n*log_2(3)) = 2^O(n)`

`log_2(3) = z` means "2 to the power of z gives me 3" and we are raising 2 to this exponent, so we get `3^n`.

Basically they showed that by multiplying the exponent in `2^x` by a constant, you can change the base to 3. Big O drops constants, so it doesn't matter if the base is 2 or 3.

Edit:

```
If f(n) = 3^n and g(n) = 2^n 

The 3 in 2^(n*log_2(3)) must be coming from f(n)?
The 2 in 2^(n*log_2(3)) must be coming from g(n)'s base?
----> Is the log_2 a constant??
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here. log_2 of a constant number is a constant.

```
4^(n*log_2(7))

Where k = 7, and n >= 7 and 2 is the constant 'c'?
```

Your "answer" should be `7^n = 4^O(n)`. Your way of showing this is `7^n = 4^(n*log_4(7)) = 4^O(n)`, as `4^log_4(7) = 7`.

Comment: Actually I removed it, not sure if it's right because it does seem like it is what you're supposed to do based on that textbook quote about exponentials. @FoxDonut I'm trying to make sense of it now.

Comment: Yes, i think you were looking at the random constant I chose lol

Comment: I would really appreciate that. It seems really odd that I could be THAT far off when following the book's example. The problem is that I don't have access to the answer. If you'd like, i can take a picture of the text so you can see the entire paragraph.

Comment: Your definition for Big O is incomplete. You need to pick a high enough starting point. See this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition. This picture may also help, notice that cg(n) becomes the upper bound only after some point k: https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/Images/bigOGraph.gif

Comment: I added the paragraph. Unfortunately, that is all the information that is given in the chapter about this topic. I will look at the link you provided.

Also, if f(n) is not ALWAYS = to O(g(n)), then wouldn't the answer be false? You said that it was only after a certain point right?

Comment: No, the _definition_ of big O only requires the function to act as an upper bound after a certain point. So to say f(n) = O(g(n)), you only need to show that g(n) acts as an upper bound of f(n) after a certain point. The relationship between 2 functions in terms of big O will be the same regardless of the input.

Comment: In your case, using `c > log_2(3)` should work in your proof as this is the point at which the bases become the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for all you've said. Can you please explain one more thing? How do you obtain a suitable k, as in n >= k, and just as importantly - how do we get to using a logarithm? There must be some type of formula? @Zar

Comment: There isn't a formula, you just have to make an educated guess. One way of approaching this could be trying to solve `3 = 2^c`, which will give you the log. Remember that you're trying to find the point after which g(n) will always be >= f(n). @FoxDonut

Comment: Sorry @Zar i feel silly and you are so intelligent i'm probably frustrating you.. but yes, i'm still confused a bit. For visual sake, i'm going to edit my original post so I can ask you my final question (I promise).

Comment: not sure if you changed your answer since last time I looked - but it's more helpful than the last time I read it haha. Though, in my last edit I assumed that the 3 was the starting point for n>=k, where k is 3. That is not correct. I guess i'm having a tough time wrapping my head around finding the k's starting point lol.

Comment: I totally understand this now!!!! I did some testing and this fulfills f(n) <= c*g(n) for all n>= k, even when k = 1. Finally, I can get some sleep - and you don't have to deal with me anymore!!! hahah. Thanks! Seriously, a very BIG thanks!

Comment: Np. I don't really understand your defn because k isn't defined, but as long as it works for you lol.

Comment: My definition was that f(n) = O(g(n)) if positive integers c and k exist such that for every integer n >= k, f(n) <= c*g(n).